# preg_replace not working in snippet

Tags: php, modx, modx-evolution

I am tying to use the following modx evo snippet (naming it "removespace") to output the tv removing any space in the string:

```
<?php
$string1 = "[*longtitle*]"; 
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string1);
return $string;
?>
```

But calling the snippet [[removespace]] in the template does not produce the string with space removed. It produces the string as is.

But inserting the text "Hello world" in the $string1 variable produces the result without any space.

Any solution?

Comment: There are no spaces in `[*longtitle*]`

Comment: My longtitle is "Welcome to my website" and there are 3 spaces there. I want to output it like Welcometomywebsite. Looks weird, but I have a reason for that. If you are familiar with MODx, you know what I mean.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MODx. I guess it replaces the keyword in the variable for you?

Comment: it appears to be working on interactive shell, perhaps the problem is on the template not on the php part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use MODX tags as is inside the snippets, you will need to use `$modx->documentObject['variable-name']`

So your code will be something like this:

```
<?php
$string1 = $modx->documentObject['longtitle']; 
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string1);
return $string;
?>
```